# Ubuntu VM shows 50GB, but df -h shows 30GB

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, disk

I have an Ubuntu VM on VMWare Player, on which I can't increase the virtual disk size. Earlier I built the VM with 30G size, then I used the VMWare expand 'button' to expand to 50G. Now the VMWare image shows 50G. But when I do a `df -h` inside the OS, I still see it as 30G.

`fdisk -l` shows disk as 50G, but the sda1 partition still shows 30G. How can I extend my / (everything is on /, just one partition) to the full 50G?

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0001183e

Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048 58722303 58720256  28G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       58724350 62912511  4188162   2G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       58724352 62912511  4188160   2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have increased the partition, but not the **filesystem**.    The garage now holds two SUV's, but the car in it is still the same VW Beetle.

Comment: Which filesystem? please add the output of "mount" to the question

Answer (score 3):

The expansion grows the virtual hard disk, but without doing anything with its content. It is like if you had cloned a physical 30G hard disk to a 50G one:

- also the partition table on your virtual disk remained the same, so it points now to a 30G partition (on the already 50G disk).
- furthermore, your sda1 still holds a 30G partition, even if you update the partition table, it remain still 30G.

The solution is very simple:

1. Reboot your virtual machine into a virtual Ubuntu live ISO image.
2. Use the `parted` tool to extend 1) your sda1 partition 2) the filesystem on it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here. https://askubuntu.com/a/116367/349090

1. removed existing partitions
2. created new main(pri) part.
3. created swap part.
   rebooted.
4. ran resize2fs

I followed all steps in there, it worked nicely. I thought I would delete my question. But then, maybe someone will come asking the same thing....

Thank you.